# Is that possible to get view from absolute x and y coordinated in android?

Tags: android, events, view

I am trying to do is

`MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x, y, 0);
v.dispatchTouchEvent(e);`

i want to dispatch touch event , if i know the absolute x and y axis , can i get the view located at (x,y) coordinate ?

Comment: Did u get the ans ? Even i am looking for the same.